# linking to third-party static library: "file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)"

Tags: ios, static-libraries

I am trying to use a third-party open-source C++ static library. I downloaded the archive from the project's web site, ran `./configure --disable-shared`, then `make`, `make test`, and `make install`. (I'm a UNIX novice so this was just following the instructions on the project's web site.)

In Xcode, I added the .a files from the `lib` folder under Link Binary With Libraries, added the `include` folder to the Header Search Paths, and added `-ObjC` to Other Linker Flags (though I don't think that one is important since the library is C++).

When I try to build the project, I get several warnings like

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/<my name>/Dropbox/Computing/COIN-OR/Cbc-2.8.10/lib/libOsiCbc.a, 
file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): 
/Users/<my name>/Dropbox/Computing/COIN-OR/Cbc-2.8.10/lib/libOsiCbc.a
```

and several errors like

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_CbcOrClpReadCommand", referenced from:
  CoinReadNextField() in CbcOrClpParam.o
```

I'm aware there are many threads on Stack Overflow about this error, and the solution is to include the right architectures (arm and i386) when compiling the library. But since this is a third-party library, I'm not compiling it in Xcode. Is there some way to fix this problem in the shell steps I listed above?

Since it's open source I can get the source code, but I don't know how to build the library at that point.

Answer (score 0):

How to build depends on how the open source code was wrote. But most library use the configure parameters to do this. Maybe there's a parameter looks like `./configure --arch i386` then `make && make install`. You should find out it from the `README` or `How to use` documents. Or you'd better ask the author.

After you've compiled them, you can combine several `.a` files using the `lipo` command before you added to your project

```
lipo -create /path/to/one.a /path/to/another.a -output libOsiCbc.a
```

Comment: Couldn't find anything in the documentation about adding other architectures. But looking into it...